# How do black holes form without violating the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, quantum-gravity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Many videos on YouTube while discussing black holes mention that it's born out of a heavy star when it collapses into a single point and that infinitely curves spacetime around it.

When all the mass is getting confined to one point isn't it violating the uncertainty principle?

Comment: The mass in a black hole is not confined to a point. Apart from the corner case of a completely uncharged black hole without any angular momentum this isn't even predicted by the classical theory. The aim of quantum gravity research is, of course, to understand how the classical theory derives from a proper quantum theory of spacetime and gravity.

Comment: So the entire mass of the star remains outside the singularity but red-shifted into invisibility?

Comment: We don't know what happens inside the event horizon of a black hole, but we do know that not even the classical theory predicts a point-like singularity. That's just the oversimplified version that has been circulating outside of the expert literature. I wish I could give you an easy mental model for what the theory really seems to predict, but I admit that I can't visualize it properly, either. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram.

Comment: @Weezy No. As an example, the neutron star already had a core that was in the center. And when it collapses to form a black hole the part in the core does **not** jump outwards to get outside of the event horizon. The event horizon is something people on the outside never see, you see the parts from before the horizon formed. Including the parts in the center, you just see them from before the event horizon formed there. And you see the outer layers from before the event horizon got there. And you always see the parts outside the horizon.